# JS only works if the page is refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I know there are similar questions out there, but I can't figure out why I still getting this error. The JS function works fine the first time the page is loaded but then, I have to refresh the whole page to make it work again. The response is a dynamic html that refreshes a div with new information.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- delete image function -->

<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.delete_image').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var rowid = $(this).attr('data-row-id');
        var rowprg = <?php echo $prog_id; ?>;
        var roworg = $(this).attr('data-org');
        var dataString = 'rowid=' + rowid + '&roworg=' + roworg + '&rowprg=' + rowprg;                  
        var parent = $("#"+rowid);                  
        bootbox.dialog({
                message: "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Estas seguro que quieres eliminar esta imagen?</div>",
        title: "<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i> Eliminar Imagen!",
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "No",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function() {
                    $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                }
            },
            danger: {
                label: "Eliminar",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'delete_records.php',
                        data: dataString,
                    })
                    .done(function(response){
                        bootbox.alert('Imagen eliminada satisfactoriamente!');
                        $("#cardis").html(response);
                    })
                    .fail(function(){
                        bootbox.alert('Error. No se pudo eliminar imagen');
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I have another JS function that uploads images to the server and works fine, but also after uploading an image, the delete function, the one I'm having problems with, doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You need to change your click event handler to $('.delete_image').on("click", function(e){});

Comment: @jgetner. Thanks for answering. I changed what you suggested but still cannot make it work without refreshing the page. I tried moving the "delete function"  before the div, after the div, in the header and in the bottom of the page, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your html is dynamic, so to make sure your `.delete_image` always works, you need to bind the click event in this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_image', function(e){
  ...
})
```

Comment: You nailed it. I spent 3 days trying to figure out what was it. I'm still learning the difference between $('.delete_image').click(function(e),     $('.delete_image').on("click", function(e) and  $(document).on('click', '.delete_image', function(e). All of them work fine the first time but only your solution works all the time as it should be expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can find the difference between **event handlers** and **delegated event handlers** here: https://api.jquery.com/on/